# Help understanding example in Engel's *Problem Solving Strategies*

Tags: contest-math, proof-explanation

[image]

I've spent a lot of time trying to follow the chain of reasoning, but to no avail. I lose track of how it works at the "Adding (1) and (2)" part.

Could someone help me understand this, please?

Comment: This is a typo: the unnumbered displayed equation should be numbered (1), displayed equation (1) should be numbered (2) (then "Adding (1) and (2)" is correct), displayed equation (2) should be numbered (3), and the question in the last paragraph should ask about (3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out (largely thanks to [@Did's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921162/help-understanding-example-in-engels-problem-solving-strategies#comment1901567_921162)).

Here's the complete proof.

Consider the point $(a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n)$ in 4-space. Its distance from the origin is
$$
a_{n+1}^2 + b_{n+1}^2 + c_{n+1}^2 + d_{n+1}^2 = 2(a_n^2 + b_n^2 + c_n^2 + d_n^2) - 2(a_nb_n + b_nc_n +c_nd_n + a_nd_n) \;\;(1)
$$
Now, since $a_n + b_n + c_n + d_n \gt 0$ for all $n \gt 0$,
$$
\begin{align*}
0 \;
&= (a_{n} + b_{n} + c_{n} + d_{n})^2\\
&= (a_n + c_n)^2 + (b_n + d_n)^2 + 2(a_nb_n + b_nc_n +c_nd_n + a_nd_n)
 \end{align*}
$$
This implies
$$-2(a_nb_n + b_nc_n +c_nd_n + a_nd_n) = 
(a_n + c_n)^2 + (b_n + d_n)^2 \;\;\;\;(2)
$$
Now we can add $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get

$$ \begin{align*}
a_{n+1}^2 + b_{n+1}^2 + c_{n+1}^2 + d_{n+1}^2 &= 2(a_n^2 + b_n^2 + c_n^2 + d_n^2) + (a_n + c_n)^2 + (b_n + d_n)^2\\
&\ge 2(a_n^2 + b_n^2 + c_n^2 + d_n^2)\\
&\ge 2^2(a_{n-1}^2 + b_{n-1}^2 + c_{n-1}^2 + d_{n-1}^2)\\
&\ge \cdots\\
&\ge 2^{n-j}(a_{n-j}^2 + b_{n-j}^2 + c_{n-j}^2 + d_{n-j}^2)\\
&\ge \cdots\\
&\ge 2^n(a_1^2 + b_1^2 + c_1^2 + d_1^2)
 \end{align*} 
$$

Hence the distance of the point $(a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n)$ increases exponentially in 4-space, etc., etc., etc. $\square$

PS. If there are any errors, please tell me!

Comment: I hink that's fine. Except that I never like $\ldots$ in a proof. I'd try to do a proper induction on $n$